# Finder thinks there are many nonexistent volumes named "m"

Tags: finder, external-disk, mount

I have a clumsy but mostly working AppleScript that ejects all partitions on one of my external drives except for the partition called Data OWC4_500.

The first commands in the script are

```
tell application "Finder"
get name of startup disk
get name of every disk whose ejectable = true
```

My problem is that occasionally Finder thinks that in addition to the genuine mounted volumes there are a gazillion volumes named "m". The script gets stuck looking for these nonexistent "m" volumes and won't quit. I have to force quit the script and relaunch the Finder and then the nonexistent "m" volumes go away. If I force quit the script but don't relaunch the Finder, the script will get stuck again.

Here's the AppleScript output when I'm having trouble

```
tell application "Finder"
get name of startup disk
    --> "Macintosh HD"
get name of every disk whose ejectable = true
    --> {"Data OWC4_500", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m"}
```

And here are the results of a "mount" command in Terminal - no "m" volumes anywhere to be found

```
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/Data OWC4_500 (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?